# Sending one long ping (with big waiting timeout) vs sending multiple short pings

Tags: c#, .net, networking, ping, icmp

Is there any difference between sending one long ping (with big waiting timeout) and sending multiple short pings (with short waiting timeout)?

*I am writing in C# and using Ping.Send / Ping.SendAsync methods for sending pings but guess it is general question.*

**EDIT**

I understand that sending ping to some addresses can take a long time and the comparison is not very clear. What I am really interested in is can the result of sending long ping be false and the disjunction of results of sending multiple short pings be true?

Comment: Other then the fact that a single ping can only have one result and multiple pings has multiple results?

Comment: @Amit Definetly and the question is long_ping_result = short_ping_result_1 | ... | short_ping_result_n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, imagine that for a given server it takes 1s for the ping response to arrive. If you send one ping with a long timeout of 2s, you will get a response. But if you send 20 pings with a short timeout of 0.1s, you will not get any response, but 20 timeouts.

Edit:

> can the result of sending long ping be false and the disjunction of
>   results of sending multiple short pings be true?

Yes. A ping is not 100% reliable, e.g. there may be packet loss or the server may be under heavy load and delay/ignore the request.